# Custom SCSS Seemingly Not Referenced

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am building a React site which uses the Grommet UX framework. Part of my site uses chat control where I want to apply the style of the chat control.  The issue is my custom.css doesn't appear to be applying the style to web control but rather seems to keep trying to apply Grommet.

What exactly am I missing?

Custom CSS

```
customstyle{

    body .wc-app, .wc-app button, .wc-app input, .wc-app textarea {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
...
};
```

Here is my app.js

```
import webchatstyles from '../app/custom.scss';
...
 render() {
    return (
      <App centered={false}>
        <Article>
            <Split flex='right'>
              <Section>
                <Box margin='none' pad='none'>
                  <Chat className={webchatstyles.customstyle} directLine={{secret: 'GUID.Is.Here'}} user={{id:'test', name: 'test'}}/>
                </Box>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by making the following changes:

- app.js: removed variable name from import statement
- app.js: Changed

  custom.scss: Add Height and Width    properties to .wc-chatview-panel
  so that the chat pane appears docked    on the left side of the
  screen